# how to undo powertop autotune settings?

Tags: 14.04, powertop

I installed powertop in order to increase my laptop battery life. However, after the first usage I wasn't able to shut down my laptop. And later some strange things started to happen: laptop suddenly just shut down (once) and some USB hardware disabled.

How to undo powertop autotune settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `sudo powertop --auto-tune` is not persisted. Thus a reboot sets everything back to normal. If only one setting is bothering you (and you have an idea which it is) you can always `sudo powertop` and on the last tab change the appropriate setting back from `Good` to `Bad` (by selecting that line and hitting Enter).

Comment: Is it possible to  undo `powertop --auto-tune` via a command?  because I'm writing a systemd service, and I want it work correct when the service stopped.